# Symfony3 testing the redirectToRoute() method with phpunit

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony-3.2

I am trying to make one of the most simplest (I think) functional test by PHPUnit for a Symfony3 controller.

My controller code is just a redirect:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_dashboard', array(), 301);
    }
}
```

and my test function is as follows:

```
class DefaultControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $client = static::createClient(array(), array(
            'HTTP_HOST' => 'www.admin.dev',
        ));

        $client->request('GET', '/');
        $client->followRedirect();
        $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isRedirect('/dashboard/'));
    }
}
```

The error that I get here is as follows:

```
LogicException: The request was not redirected
```

Also some of the results that I get for some values are as follows:

```
$client->getRequest()->getUri() -> "http://www.admin.dev/"
$client->getResponse()->getStatusCode() -> 404
$client->getResponse() instanceof RedirectResponse -> false
$client->getResponse()->headers->get('location') -> null
```

A little more background for this issue:

- I have multiple domains pointing to this same project
- The bundle is only loaded when the relative domain is asked for.

For example:

```
www.admin.dev -> admin bundle
www.admin2.dev -> admin2 bundle
www.admin3.dev -> admin3 bundle
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong that I am stuck with this simple problem?

My routing configuration is:

```
homepage:
    host: "www.%domain%"
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Default:index}

admin_dashboard:
    host: "www.%domain%"
    prefix:   /dashboard
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Dashboard:index}
```

And

```
%domain% is a parameter in the parameter file. The value is 'admin.dev'
```

Comment: `$client->getResponse()->getStatusCode() -> 404` looks like your `indexAction` route isn't even triggered - take a look at the logs and the `router:debug` command (and perhaps post results).

Comment: My debug:router does not normally work. So, for getting the proper routes, I need to define my environment as:
`php bin/console debug:router --env=dev_frontend`

Comment: Are you sure your unit test runs in the same environment?

Comment: Actually I am not sure about it and I am very curious to know that. Is there any way that you can define the environment? I think the tests are always running on the 'test' environment.

Comment: You can specify the environment in the createClient method, just add `'environment' => 'my_test_env',` to the 1st parameter array. (Replacing with the correct environment ofcourse)

Comment: it gives me an error of:

    `You have requested a non-existent service "test.client"`

Comment: The test client is only available if the `framework.test` option is enabled. My guess is you're importing different routes in different environments. If that's the case you should either specify a testing-environment for each of your normal environmens where the `framework.test` option is enabled or re-think your routing strategy. Currently it just looks like your routes aren't even loaded (because you're in the testing environment) and thus you get a 404. Oops: Didn't see you answered yourself down there - should probably accept that so it's at the top! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I solved it. Thanks to [ccKep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1179287/cckep) for pointing me to the right direction. All my domains had their own environment and hence, all the routes were not available. Like:

```
www.admin.dev -> loads routes for only admin bundle
www.admin2.dev -> loads routes for only admin2 bundle
www.admin3.dev -> loads routes for only admin3 bundle
```

So, to solve the problem I first debug the routes for the 'test' environment (as this environment is responsible for the tests) by calling:

```
php bin/console debug:router --env=test
```

and found that it only includes the generic routes and not the domain specific routes. So, to have the routes to be included in my test environment, I included the routing information of my domain into my test routing file.

### For those who are still curious about my strange configuration:

I have 3 domains pointing to my project:

```
www.admin.dev
www.admin2.dev
www.admin3.dev
```

Depending on this domains, the bundles are loaded as:

```
www.admin.dev  -> loads MyAdminBundle
www.admin2.dev -> loads MyAdmin2Bundle
www.admin3.dev -> loads MyAdmin3Bundle
```

Each of my domains have 2 environment of them as:

```
www.admin.dev  -> dev_admin  and prod_admin
www.admin2.dev -> dev_admin2 and prod_admin2
www.admin3.dev -> dev_admin3 and prod_admin3
```

And based on these domains and their environment, I have my configuration and routing defined so that when `www.domain.dev` is called, it uses the configuration, routing and the respective bundle based on its environment and nothing of the MyAdmin2Bundle or MyAdmin3Bundle or any of their routes or configuration.

To make it a bit more clear, I have configuration files like:

```
config.yml
config_dev.yml
config_dev_domain.yml
config_dev_domain2.yml
config_dev_domain3.yml
config_prod.yml
config_prod_domain.yml
config_prod_domain2.yml
config_prod_domain3.yml
config_test.yml
```

And routing files like:

```
routing.yml
routing_dev.yml
routing_dev_domain.yml
routing_dev_domain2.yml
routing_dev_domain3.yml
routing_prod.yml
routing_prod_domain.yml
routing_prod_domain2.yml
routing_prod_domain3.yml
routing_test.yml
```

Now what I have done it, just included the routing files of domain, domain2 and domain3 into the `routing_test.yml`.
I hope this is enough to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You are try this . it is work.

```
$host="www.admin.dev" // $host= "http://127.1.1.2(local ip)"

public function testIndex()
{
    $client = static::createClient(array(), array(
        'HTTP_HOST' => $host,
    ));
    $client->request('GET', '/forgetpass');
    $this->assertEquals(true,$client->getResponse()->isRedirect('/dashboard'));
}
```

Comment: I had already tried this. The value for $client->getResponse()->isRedirect('/dashboard') is always false.

Comment: Can you write route configuration? remove this code $client->followRedirect();
?

Comment: Sorry I was unable to format the code properly in my reply, so I have edited my original post and added the route configuration.

Comment: The value for $client->getResponse()->isRedirect('/dashboard/') is always false

Comment: I think this '  host: "www.%domain%"'  caused error :/ 
Firstly my code is false but ı remove         $client->followRedirect();
then return true :)('sory my engilish is not good ')